# Structs, pointers and memory allocation

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
//The struct
typedef struct {
    int nr;
    char *nume, **mesaj;
} utilizator;

void citire_mesaje(utilizator *user, int n)
{
    user->nr = malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    scanf("%d", &user[0].nr);
    printf("user[0].nr = %d\n", user[0].nr);
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    utilizator *user = malloc (sizeof(utilizator)); 
    citire_mesaje(user, n);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I used user[0].nr just to test it more easily. I can get it work if I only use one element of type struct (utilizator user;), but I can't figure it out if I use a pointer. I get:

```
 warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
 user->nr = malloc (n * sizeof(int));
           ^
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you do not need `user->nr = malloc (n * sizeof(int))` because it is already secured area. On the contrary nr update by `scanf` (is making an area that can not be released) memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, `nr` is an array of `int` and not just `int`. Fix it's declaration:

```
typedef struct {
    int * nr;
    char *nume, **mesaj;
} utilizator;
```

If you only want one `int`, don't call `malloc`. It will be allocated as part of your `utilizator` object (funny word btw).

Comment: I want it to be just an int. I dont have to allocate memory for it?

Comment: This line `user->nr = malloc (n * sizeof(int));` suggests that you want `n` ints, and not just one. If you just want one `int`, don't call `malloc`.

Comment: You don't have to do malloc for nr. You can use it directly by assigning a value.

Answer (score 0):

First, you do not need to `user->nr = malloc (n * sizeof(int));`  because `nr` is just an `int` and it have its own memory space of length `sizeof(int) bytes`.

Secondly and most important,

> You are not including the header file `#include <stdlib.h>`. Beacuse of this, the malloc function is implicitly declared to return int. Since you are treating the result as a pointer, there is a type-mismatch warning there.

All you have to do is, include the file `stdlib.h`.

`void*` will be safely promoted to any other pointer type in this case.

So, your code should be something like this::

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int nr;
    char *nume, **mesaj;
} utilizator;

void citire_mesaje(utilizator *user, int n)
{
    scanf("%d", &user[0].nr);
    printf("user[0].nr = %d\n", user[0].nr);
    return ;

}
int main()
{
    int n = 0 ;
    utilizator *user = malloc (sizeof(utilizator)); 
    citire_mesaje(user, n);
    free( user ) ;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating the memory for your variables the wrong way. You should use the `casting` (change the type of the value returned by `malloc` to the type of the variable):

```
// In the citire_mesaje function
user->nr = (int) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
// In the main function
utilizator *user = (utilizator *) malloc (sizeof(utilizator));
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
//The struct
typedef struct {
    int nr;
    char *nume, **mesaj;
} utilizator;

void citire_mesaje(utilizator *user, int n)
{
    user->nr = (int) malloc (n * sizeof(int));
    printf("Enter a value for user[0].nr: ");
    scanf("%d", &user[0].nr);
    printf("user[0].nr = %d\n", user[0].nr);
}
int main()
{
    int n; // make sure to inisialize the n variable
    utilizator *user = (utilizator *) malloc (sizeof(utilizator));
    citire_mesaje(user, n);

    return 0;
}
```